# SQL error in DELETE function?

Tags: php, sql

Hi I'm getting this SQL error, and I'm not seeing what I'm doing wrong...

I'm getting:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM forums WHERE id=2' at line 1

Code:

```
$remove_forum = "DELETE * FROM forums WHERE id=$selected_option";
$run_remove_forum = mysql_query("$remove_forum") or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just DELETE FROM
(* is for choosing columns and here you're not choosing any)

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you remove the '*'? As far as I know on standard SQL it is not necessary...

Answer (score 0):

remove `*` and use `DELETE FROM forums WHERE id=$selected_option`

Answer (score 0):

WRONG SYNTAX

change

```
$remove_forum = "DELETE * FROM forums WHERE id=$selected_option";
```

with

```
$remove_forum = "DELETE FROM forums WHERE id=$selected_option";
```

Also I think you could do without quotes when you pass the variable to mysql_query
(this way)

```
$run_remove_forum = mysql_query($remove_forum) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

we can use `*` for only those queries which returns something like select query

Comment: Will be fine if you can improve answer quality, with samples or more details which help solve the problem.